# UBUNTU: XOpenDisplay(NULL) fails when program run in boot sequence via rc.local

Tags: ubuntu, x11, rc

I have written a program that runs with ROOT permission in Terminal following login but fails when XOpenDisplay(NULL) call is made following reboot.  The program is started up via rc.local but doesn't appear to be able to see X11.

I need ROOT because I make LibUSB calls and these fail if not ROOT.  I can see the program is running with ROOT permission but inspection of environment variables shows DISPLAY not set.  I have a delay loop running and checks are made after user login and user can see DISPLAY set in environment variables but program cannot.  If program is terminated and run in Terminal it works perfectly so the problem is that the program cannot interact with X11 when it is started and this state persists.

I want the program to be up and running without user login.

Can anyone let me know what I need to do?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to tripleee.

Ubuntu now uses LightDM and so by adding the line below to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
greeter-setup-script=usr/bin/'my-script'
```

where 'my-script' is:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/'my-prog' &
```

everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Your program should only start once X11 is up and running. But a much better design is to make a service which runs with root privileges, but doesn't use X, and arrange for an X client to talk to it somehow. If you cannot exist without X, hook into the X11 startup sequence, rather than the system startup.

Comment: Ok.  So how can I tell if X11 is running?   Shouldn't X11 be running when rc.local is run as this happens after rc5 which is when X11 starts.

Comment: Updated my answer; better to not depend on X11 at all for the USB stuff.

Comment: So when would I run the X client given that I want everything up and running before the login has been done?  I think the client will hit the same issue - when should it run.

Comment: I'm looking at hooking into /etc/X11/Xsession.d and I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: With a 95name I can get the program to start and run (via sudo) with ROOT however it only loads after login which isn't what I want.  More thinking and head scratching tonight.  Obviously, first thing will be to rename to 05name.

Comment: Xsession only happens when a user logs in and starts a session. You want to look at the stuff which runs the login dialog (does Ubuntu still use `gdm`?)

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/74189/run-a-startup-script-with-lightdm and perhaps https://answers.launchpad.net/lightdm/+question/174892