# QT gui application not starting automatically on startup in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, shell, ubuntu-14.04, startup

I have two Qt applications, one is non gui called "App1" and another one is gui called "App2". As per my need I need to start "App1" on startup of Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

This "App1" runs a sh file called "myshfile.sh" and I am starting "App2" into this shell script file by /opt/myprojectname/App2 &

So to do the same I make .sh file called "myupstart.sh" and write into /opt/myprojectname/App1 & it and copy the file at path /etc/init.d/ and gave it +x permission to start "App1" on startup.

When I restart my machine then it runs "App1" (which is qt non-gui app) automatically on startup and runs "myshfile.sh" as expected. Till now all are working fine but the problem occurs from here as per below.

As I have mentioned above that "App1" runs a sh file called "myshfile.sh" and I am starting "App2" into the shell script file by /opt/myprojectname/App2 &  but "App2" is not staring ( which is qt gui app).

When I do the same by simply running command into termianl /opt/myprojectname/App1 then all works fine and it calls the "myshfile.sh" file and "myshfile.sh" file also starts "App2".

So what I found that when I do the same by manually into termianl then all works fine and by script etc/init.d/myupstart.sh, it starts only Qt non-gui application and not starting Qt gui application on startup.

Kindly suggest me where I am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Starting GUI apps is not related to init.d or shells. It is an X / Unity / KDE thing. You need a different mechanism (From the top of my head, I don't know which), and you want to execute it after you logged in, probably, not before that. This e.g.: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/execute-a-command-on-user-logon

Comment: Thanks,  Ronny Brendel  for your reply. Yes, I need to run it after the logged into the machine. I will try as per link you have suggested and will see if it works.

Comment: I have written  command "/opt/myprojectname/App1 &  " in ~/.profile file and Now it starts gui and non gui qt program on restart but it starts logged in uses privileges instead of root privileges. I want to start these qt application with root privileges. Have you any idea how can start the same with root privileges ?

Comment: Maybe this?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118472/how-do-i-launch-a-gui-application-as-root-on-user-login

Comment: Thanks Ronny Brendel , it works but I have one issue, in the above link I need to write " username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/command " in /etc/sudoers file. In which I need to  write "username" hardcode but I want  make it smart enough so that it can use logged in username instead of hardcode value. Btw I am working on the same.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe post another question. (And perhaps remove this one, since it's kind of a duplicate with one of the links I posted)

Comment: Ronny Brendel, Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UBUNTU: XOpenDisplay(NULL) fails when program run in boot sequence via rc.local](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517333/ubuntu-xopendisplaynull-fails-when-program-run-in-boot-sequence-via-rc-local)